# plan to deploy Spring boot app, which container is better, Jetty or tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, jetty

We plan to deploy Spring boot app, which container is better, Jetty or tomcat?

or just run the jar with command java -jar?

Here is the requirement:

It is a web app, the frontend is ReactJS, the backend is Spring Boot.
And we also plan to install the Apache or Nginx to
 route the frontend page and backend API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat, which is the default is better in my opinion.

If you want to step it up a notch pick Undertow.

Tomcat is good and just works. Jetty works too but should be preferred over tomcat (one reason is support by default). Some people started worrying about performance and thus switched to Undertow (or changed their whole architecture to use wildfly swarm). The performance advantages are hardly noticed unless you scale horizontally much.

Comment: got  it, thx for that.